# Set-overlay collection of polygons on itself

Tags: shapely, geopandas, overlay

I have a GeodataFrame in Geopandas, that consists of a number of polygons, each overlapping its neighbors. What I want is to generate every single possible polygon from all the intersections, so that the resulting polygons won't overlap each other, and on unary_union will return the equivalent to the unary_union of the original dataset. How would you achieve that?